# Fishpig Magento: In which table Product and blog relation are saved?

Tags: magento, magento2, fishpig

I am new to Magento. I have connected the WordPress using Fishpig and assigned a blog to the product. Now I am checking in the Magento table where Magento stores the relation of product and blog in DB.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Related Products add-on module? Is this how you are setting up the post -> product link?

If so, you do not need to know the table as the module provides methods to access this data so please review the module code for more information.

If you still want to know the table name, the table is stored in the WordPress database (as WordPress doesn't have access to the Magento DB). The table names are as follows (you may not use wp_ as your table prefix so this may be different for you).

wp_related_products
wp_related_categories